# Store a value in a text file to a variable and return it

Tags: python, text

Is there a way to read a particular value in a text file and store it in a variable?
For example, I have the following value for loss in my file:

```
Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.578 dB
```

Is there a way I can retrieve only the frequency point and the value after the equals sign and store that value in a variable which can be returned by a function in python?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look over the string methods yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
s = """Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.578 dB
Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -1.011 dB"""
freq = re.findall("\@\s+(.*)GHz", s)
val = re.findall("GHz\s+\=(.*)dB", s)
for i in zip(freq, val):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
('2.500000e+00 ', ' -0.578 ')
('5 ', ' -1.011 ')
```

Comment: So if there are multiple lines of losses for different frequencies like: Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.578 dB
Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -1.011 dB, how would I change it?

Comment: Doing it sequentially for each search will be tedious if there are multiple lines to read right?

Comment: You can use `re.findall`

Comment: so m becomes a list of all the values?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: So for multiple lines, I have to Keep adding those lines into s? Isn't it really tedious if this goes to 100 or 200 values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170650/discussion-between-potato-and-rakesh).

Comment: Chat is blocked.

Comment: oh ok I get this error for s=filename.read() : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    l=[]
    for line in file.readlines():
        line_array = line.split(' ')
        l.append=(line_array[0], line_array[4], line_array[7])
```

after this the `l` will be :

```
[
  ('Loss', '2.500000e+00', '-0.578')
]
```

tell me if you need those values in different structure not a list of tuples.